# Show versions in .jsp pages

Tags: java, svn, jsp, version

I need to put versions of my software in my jsp pages. Can I do it trough XML files? Can Subversion record this in files that has been versioned?

thankful

Daniel Alves da Fonseca Maciel

Answer (score 2):

[Subversion keyword substitution](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.4/svn.advanced.props.special.keywords.html) might do the trick, for example, add something similar to in each of your jsps:

```
<!-- 
$LastChangedDate$
$Rev$
-->
```

Then everytime you commit, svn should replace the $keywords$ with the appropriate value. See the svnbook for more details.

Comment: Every jsp page will have a different version number, if you do it like this. This may or may not be after what OP is after. $LastChangedDate$ expands to date when current file was last modified.

Answer (score 1):

To create version number that is same across all the JSP pages.

1. Have your build process create a file that contains the version number.

   - execute something like this in your build: `svnversion -c trunk > version.txt`
2. Package `version.txt` with your web application (inside .war file).
3. Create a function to read version information from the `version.txt` file
4. Call function from JSP pages and display version information. (Preferably from some footer/header fragment that is included in every page).